# Need additional information to be populated while joining datasets in spark using user defined function

Tags: apache-spark, join, apache-spark-dataset

I am trying to join datasets in Spark using a user defined function (UDF) as the logic to join is complex. For example:

I have two datasets "one" and "two" of below mentioned bean:

```
class Bean {
   private String id;
   private String name;
}
```

My join condition is:

```
If ids are equal
   match confidence = 100%
else if names are equal
   match confidence = 50%
else
   do not join the rows
```

I can easily create a user defined function to check the columns in this order but how do I provide the confidence score to the output joined dataset?

Answer (score 1):

I would do two joins.

First on on id, adding a field `confidence` and setting it to 100

Then a join on names, also adding the field `confidence`, now setting it to 50

Then do a union of those datasets, grouping by id and keeping highest confidence

Perhaps cache the original datasets because they are being used twice, handy to keep in memory

This also reduces the need of udfs for joins, which are sometimes computational heavy, because they are in essence black boxes for catalyst

Comment: Was this useful? Otherwise please post some sample data